# Facebook recommendations on my website displaying some Tiwan website url?

Tags: facebook, widget

I'm using Facebook recommendations on my blog( http://techdreams.org ) to display most liked/shared content. Today I noticed that top most link on my sites recommendations is from an unknown site with url "http://79h.taiwan-talk.org/like.php?pid=822".

Can someone please help me to get rid of this spam link?

[image: Tiwan site on top of facebook recommendations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an open bug in Facebook's [bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) - details here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/243312152381418

It was marked as fixed on Friday so it should be resolved now - if you're still having the issue you should follow up on that bug report or file a new one